# Limit of a generalized function

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider the function
$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{\epsilon}}
$.
It is necessary to find the limit of this function when $\epsilon \rightarrow+0$.
I know that the answer should be $\sqrt{\pi}\delta(x)$, where $\delta(x)$ is a Dirac delta function. I acted as follows, take generalized function $\phi(x)$ and consider the action of the delta function on
$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{\epsilon}}
$:
$$\left\langle
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{\epsilon}}, \phi(x)\right \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}\int_{-A}^{A}e^{-\frac{x^2}{\epsilon}}\phi(x) dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}\int_{-A}^{A}e^{-\frac{x^2}{\epsilon}}\left(\phi(x) - \phi(0)\right) dx + \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}\int_{-A}^{A}e^{-\frac{x^2}{\epsilon}}\phi(0) dx
$$
using integration by parts I get:
$$
\sqrt{\pi}erf\left(\frac{A}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}\right)\left(\phi(A) - \phi(-A)\right) - \sqrt{\pi}\int_{-A}^{A}erf\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}\right)\phi'(x)dx + \sqrt{\pi}\phi(0)erf\left(\frac{A}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}\right) = \sqrt{\pi}\phi(0)erf\left(\frac{A}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}\right) \rightarrow\sqrt{\pi}\phi(0)
$$
Where $[-A, A]$ is a ${\mathrm  {supp}}\,\phi$ and $\operatorname erf\,x={\frac  {2}{{\sqrt  {\pi }}}}\int \limits _{0}^{x}e^{{-t^{2}}}\,{\mathrm  d}t$. But this proof has a mistake and I'm unable to solve this problem. Could somebody help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. Notice that
\begin{align}
\int^A_{-A} \frac{|x|}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}e^{-x^2/\epsilon}\frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}{|x|} dx = \int^A_{-A} \frac{|x|}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}e^{-x^2/\epsilon}\frac{1}{|x|}\int^x_0 \phi'(t) dt dx.
\end{align}
Then it follows that
\begin{align}
\left|\int^A_{-A} \frac{|x|}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}e^{-x^2/\epsilon}\frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}{|x|} dx\right| \le&\, \sqrt{\epsilon}\|\phi'\|_{L^\infty} \int^A_{-A}\frac{|x|}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}e^{-x^2/\epsilon}d\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}\right)\\
 \le&\, 2\sqrt{\epsilon}\|\phi'\|_{L^\infty} \int^\infty_0 x e^{-x^2} dx \le C\sqrt{\epsilon}.
\end{align}